# Quick retrieve data from different tables using Laravel eloquent relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-optimization

My Application having 10 millions of records.

Company Table:

```
 +---+------+-----------+-------------+------------+
 |id | name |country_id | industry_id | finance_id |
 +---+------+-----------+-------------+------------+
 | 1 |LOrel |         1 |           1 |          1 |
 +---+------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

Country Table:

```
 +---+-----------+
 |id | name      |
 +---+-----------+
 | 1 |  USA      |
 +---+-----------+
 | 2 |  Romania  |
 +---+-----------+
```

Industry Table:

```
 +---+-----------+
 |id | name      |
 +---+-----------+
 | 1 |  Pharmacy |
 +---+-----------+
 | 2 |  Software |
 +---+-----------+
```

Finance Table:

```
 +---+------------+------+--------+---------+------------+
 |id | company_id | year |revenue | profit  | loss       |
 +---+------------+------+--------+---------+------------+
 | 1 |         1  | 2017 |  4,125 |    2045 |        750 |
 +---+------------+------+--------+---------+------------+
 | 2 |         1  | 2018 | 10,125 |    7045 |        125 |
 +---+------------+------+--------+---------+------------+
 | 3 |         2  | 2017 |  8,125 |    4045 |        750 |
 +---+------------+------+--------+---------+------------+
 | 4 |         3  | 2018 |  7,125 |    2045 |        125 |
 +---+------------+------+--------+---------+------------+
```

This is my database structure.

Expected output:

```
 +---------+---------+----------+-----+--------+---------+
 | Country | company | industry |year |revenue | profit  |
 +---------+---------+----------+-----+--------+---------+
 |  USA    |  LOrel  | Pharmacy |2018 | 10,125 |    7045 |
 +---------+---------+----------+-----+--------+---------+
```

I am getting same result what i want, i am using laravel eager loading and yajra laravel datatables.

Now, i need to filter data through range slider, it's takes long time to retrieve data from DB.

```
$company_data = Company::whereBetween('revenue',$request->slider)
      ->with('country','industry','company_financial')
     ->skip($request->start)->take($request->length)->get();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) or something like that.

Comment: Does this need to be updated frequently or only like once a day?

Comment: I would definitely suggest to rethink your dbms decisions. Some NOSQL Databases might fit better for your needs.

Comment: @btl  No need to update frequently. updated weekly once.

Comment: In this case you should run it as a periodic [Queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues) job via Laravel's [Task Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling)

Comment: @btl i don't know how Queue's are work for me. i don't have much experience on laravel. Please tell me how it's working.

Comment: I've posted an answer with the steps needed

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to run this query infrequently (i.e. once a week), then off load the task to the [queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues). I would suggest using redis for the driver.

Start by [creating a Job](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#creating-jobs)

```
// WeeklyQueryJob.php

protected $slider;
protected $start;
protected $length;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($slider, $start, $length)
{
    $this->slider = $slider;
    $this->start = $start;
    $this->length = $length;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    $company_data = Company::whereBetween('revenue',$this->slider)
                  ->with('country','industry','company_financial')
                  ->skip($this->start)
                  ->take($this->length)
                  ->get();

    // add logic to store/email/whatever the results
}
```

Next setup a [scheduled task to queue the job](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#scheduling-queued-jobs)

```
/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->job(new WeeklyQueryJob)->weekly();
}
```

Next, add an [entry to cron to run the scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#introduction)

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Last, use supervisor to [start the queue worker and keep it running](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#supervisor-configuration)

Comment: Thank for your answer btl, but i need to retrieve data through slider filter.

Comment: No way to automate that? You need to manually adjust it everytime?

Comment: It is easy to pass any values into a job, I've included the constructor to demonstrate how.

Comment: I am passing slider range to controller (ex [450,30,000] ), it's returns result but takes long time. i want retrieve data fast.